# Caffe | Unknown bottom blob after adding new layer to use trained model(fine tune)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I would like to fine tune `bvlc_reference_caffenet` model on my dataset.
I successfully finetuned the model. But now I am trying to add 2 more convolutional layers to check how it will perform. I tried by adding layers with names `"conv6_new"` and `"conv7_new"` after `"conv5"` layer. I copied `"conv3"` layer and pasted by renaming it as `"conv6_new"` and `"conv5"` as `"conv7_new"`. I modified names of corresponding `"ReLU"` and `"Pooling"` layers.
But I am getting following error.
Can anyone suggest me where am I making a mistake?

> ```
> F0620 17:29:49.967382 14194 insert_splits.cpp:29] Unknown bottom blob 'conv7_new' (layer 'conv7_new', bottom index 0)
> ```

Comment: please include the code

Answer (score 1):

Layer `"conv7_new"` cannot have its own output ("top") as an input as well. Make sure you rename, not only the layers' names, but also the `"top"`s and `"bottom"`s in a way that makes sense:
If you have `"conv5"` ->  `"conv6_new"` ->  `"conv7_new"` -> `"fc"`,
then you should have `"conv6_new"`'s bottom is the `"top"` of `"conv5"`, and `"conv7_new"`'s bottom is the `"top"` of `"conv6_new"`. Finally, the bottom of `"fc"` is the `"top"` of your new `"conv7_new"` layer.
Note that I ignored `"ReLU"`s that can be computed "in-place" by setting their `"top"` name identical to the `"bottom"`. I also did not include the pooling layer.

Comment: @Shai..I renamed "top"s and "bottom"s in "conv7_new" .I tried to take trained weights of fully connected layers without renaming layer's names of "fc6" and "fc7" and i renamed final layer to "fc8_new" according to my output i.e 2.  I am getting the following error...........................................F0621 09:20:56.680239 16761 net.cpp:765] Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'fc6'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 1 1 4096 9216 (37748736); target param shape is 4096 2304 (9437184).

Comment: @shai..Now I renamed the layer's names of "fc6" to "fc6_new" and "fc7" to "fc7_new" and "fc8" to "fc8_new".Now i have "conv5" ->  "conv6_new" ->  "conv7_new" -> "fc6_new" -> "fc7_new" -> "fc8_new".It is working fine.But inorder to take trained weights of "fc6" and "fc7".where i have to do modifications.Can you please suggest me.

Comment: Can somebody tell me what FC6 or fc6 stands for?

Comment: @vanilla there is an unofficial naming convention for deep nets' layers: `conv*` are `"Convolution"` layers while `fc*` are **f**ully-**c**onnected (aka `"InnerProduct"`) layers

Comment: thanks is there a cheat sheet for all those conventions? And could you help me with the meaning of conv5_2 as well?

Comment: @vanilla I don't know of any official cheat sheet for this subject. `conv5_2` usually mean the second `conv` layer in the 5th "block"